# How browser loads Javascript resources?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I did search on Google to understand how browser loads the resources (CSS, JS, Images, HTML etc) and when I did the prototype code then got little confused based on my test. Following is my plnkr code where I added `<script>` to add delay of 10 seconds to test the document load vs window load.

[Plnkr Code](http://plnkr.co/edit/p9ZdvPdLqDBfyM2A5j2A?p=preview)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script data-require="jquery" data-semver="2.1.1" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
     // executes when HTML-Document is loaded and DOM is ready
     console.log("document loaded at "+new Date());

    });
    $(window).load(function() {
     // executes when complete page is fully loaded, including all frames, objects and images
     console.log("window loaded at "+new Date());
    });
</script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1 class="red">First element :-)</h1>
   <script src="https://httpbin.org/delay/60"></script>
    <h1 class="blue">Second element:-)</h1>
  </body>

</html>
```

I have following observations and questions

1. My understanding was browser doesn't render the page until complete page is not parsed i.e. DOM is prepared. However once I tested this sample page then I do see my first H1 tag is rendered and then it waited to load the next `<script>` and then it renders the second H1 tag. Isn't page should wait to build the complete DOM first then try to render?
2. Why $(window).load and $(document).ready events are getting fired at same moment?

Comment: window.load is fired when all resources ( like images etc. ) are loaded along with the DOM while document.ready is fired when only the DOM is loaded.

Comment: Most browsers definitely start rendering even when they haven't yet received the whole page (this is quite obvious for very large pages on slow links).

Comment: Re: load/ready, you don't have any images that would delay `load`. Also note that those two events details are very browser-specific. jQuery tries to smooth things out, but I'm not sure you can count on a 100% exact same behaviour on all browsers.

Comment: Based on my testing, it seems that document.ready is fired when HTML & Javascripts are loaded, $(window).load fired when images etc are loaded as well. Does it mean that when we say DOM is loaded then we include loading of javascript as well

Comment: Most browser will start rendering as soon as they have loaded all `css` files that they are currently award if you have linked a `css` file in your `head` and you have a delay on the delivery on this one, then you most likely will see a blank screen or the previous one until the style-sheet is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

> My understanding was browser doesn't render the page until complete page is not parsed i.e. DOM is prepared.

Not true. Browsers render pages incrementally.

> Why $(window).load and $(document).ready events are getting fired at same moment?

`ready` fires as soon as the HTML document has finished rendering.

`load` fires as soon as the HTML document has finished rendering and external resources (such as images) have loaded.

You don't have any external resources other than the stylesheet (which starts loading quickly and finishes loading before the rest of the page has loaded) and the scripts (which block DOM parsing anyway).

Comment: The load event fires at the end of the document loading process. NOT necessarily after the rendering is completed.